# Has the missing dark matter in some galaxies been explained yet?

Tags: galaxy, dark-matter

There are galaxies that should have dark matter to explain their existence but they do not.

"Mystery of Galaxy's Missing Dark Matter Deepens | NASA" https://www.nasa.gov/feature/goddard/2021/mystery-of-the-galaxys-missing-dark-matter-deepens

"This weird galaxy is missing all of its dark matter and scientists can't explain it | Space" https://www.space.com/dark-matter-missing-from-galaxy

Comment: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/53314/have-we-discovered-a-galaxy-lacking-in-dark-matter Does this answer your question?

Comment: https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-022-04665-6 shows that DF2 is part of a chain formed by two galaxies passing through each other.  The stars and dark matter passed through each other unimpeded.  A chain of dwarf galaxies between them formed from gas clouds (sans dark matter) that rammed into each other.  This is called a bullet interaction.